# Generate unique patterns of numbers (e.g. 1221 considered same pattern as 2112)

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing 7 different dilutions that I want to assign into 3 different bins in all possible combinations for later use in `lpSolve`. I can generate all 2187 possible combinations using:

```
expand.grid(1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3)
```

However, since the actual *bin number* is not important (but position is), the following entries are all considered identical in this context:

```
c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)
c(2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1)
c(3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
c(3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
c(1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2)
...
```

How do I generate only unique "patterns", either by filtering `expand.grid` output or by using another (custom) function. For example, the lengths output from `rle` of all of the above vectors would be `2 3 2`, but that would also be the case for `c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1)` which should be not considered identical to the above.

Any fast way around this? I do not need to go higher than 5 bins and 8 dilutions.

Comment: (+1) very interesting problem, although Rcoster beat me to it! :P

Comment: I don't think problem is solved yet.

Comment: @Arun, interesting problem indeed. +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an answer:

```
mat <- expand.grid(1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3)

mat <- t(apply(mat, 1, 
               function(x){
                 un <- unique(x)
                 map <- setNames(1:length(un), un)
                 map[as.character(x)]
               }))

mat <- mat[!duplicated(mat), ]
nrow(mat)
# [1] 365
```

And logic is the following: let us take `c(3,3,1,2,1,2,3)` and now I convert it to `c(1,1,2,3,2,3,1)`, because `3` is the first **unique** number from the beginning, `1` is the second and `2` is the third one. In this way I convert all the rows to the same format and it allows me to use `duplicated`. `setNames` was useful here, it creates a **map** from one set of integers to another:

```
setNames(1:3,3:1)
3 2 1 
1 2 3 
setNames(1:3,3:1)[c("2","1")]
2 1 
2 3
```

Finally, the proof:

[image]

Which takes into consideration cases when one, two or three different numbers are used. In particular: [(a single number takes all 7 positions)] + [(choosing 1 position for one number and all the rest is for another) + (choosing 2 positions for one number and all the rest is for another) + (choosing 3 positions and all the rest is for another)] + [(choosing 1 position for the first number, 1 position for the second and all the rest is for the third number. Now 1st and 2nd are considered the same, and they both occur once, so we have to divide this term by two) + ...(same logic as before)...]

Comment: I'm not quite sure what this does. But the output should be of dimensions 486 * 7. On a input matrix shown from the post (2187*7), your code gives exact same output (2187*7).

Comment: @Arun, yes, output had the same dimensions, but the matrix itself was different and after using `duplicated` it reduced to 493 rows or so.

Comment: @Julius Thanks for looking into this and describing the logic behind the solution.

Comment: @KristofferW.Balling, no problem. I have updated my answer with the idea of calculating combinations.

Answer (score 2):

This?

```
data <- expand.grid(1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3)
len <- apply(data,1,function(x) c(rle(x)$lengths[1:7], nchar(paste(unique(sort(rle(x)$value)), collapse=''))))
data <- data[!(duplicated(t(len))), ]
```

Or, as @Arun pointed:

```
data <- expand.grid(1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3)
len <- apply(data,1,function(x) c(rle(x)$lengths[1:7], length(unique(x))))
data <- data[!(duplicated(t(len))), ]
```

Comment: But this would give same lengths for: `2,2,3,3,3,2,2` and `2,2,3,3,3,1,1`. Where as it is not desirable to remove the first one.

Comment: why `nchar(paste(unique(sort(.))))`? Isn't this just `length(unique(.))`?

Comment: @Arun: Yes... Don't know what I was thinking... :/

Comment: Not sure if this does it yet. It gives for example: `1,1,2,2,2,1,1` and `3,3,2,2,2,1,1`, where only the first is desirable, I believe..?

Comment: Excellent. Thanks @Rcoster That seems to do the trick. Both patterns pointed out by @Arun in the first comment are present (as `1 1 2 2 2 1 1` and `3 3 2 2 2 1 1`, respectively). Manual inspection of `data <- expand.grid(1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 1:3)` looks sound.

Comment: @Arun both `1,1,2,2,2,1,1` and `3,3,2,2,2,1,1` are desirable, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: (+1) Rcoster. @KristofferW.Balling, I think this attempt deserves an upvote (apart from accepting it as an answer)!

Comment: I don't think this is right answer, for 7 elements, choose 2 first and choose 2 from remaining 5 gives total 210 combinations. It's combinatorics question.

Comment: Infact required number of combination falls to 105 only. See my answer below

Comment: @KristofferW.Balling how is `1,1,2,2,2,1,1` desirable? that's just 2 bins no?

Comment: I am missing `1,1,1,1,2,3,1`.

Comment: @Julius you are right, `1,1,1,1,2,3,1` or equivalent (e.g. `3,3,3,3,1,2,3`) is missing.

Comment: @geektrader yes, `1,1,2,2,2,1,1` is only two bins, but what I was after was "pattern-unique" combinations of 3 bins _or less_, even if that includes putting all in one bin (e.g. `1,1,1,1,1,1,1`). If you wanted to filter only those that contain all 3 bins I guess a length(unique(x)) == 3 would do.

Comment: @KristofferW.Balling Perhaps then wording in your question was wrong or my so was my interpretation. Ended up spending couple of hours on this.. Oh well.. good question none the less

Answer (score 1):

It's combinatorics question IMO.

I think for 7 elements, you want to choose 2 first and choose 2 from remaining 5 which gives total 210 combinations.

Thanks to Arun, who pointed out that combination 11 22 333 is same as 22 11 333, we can deduce that since first 2 elements are the ones that can interchange, our required number of combinations should be half of 210 that is 105

```
library(gtools)

# Let's create all possible permutations of 7 elements which will be equal to 7!
p <- permutations(7, 7, 1:7)

head(p)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
## [1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7
## [2,]    1    2    3    4    5    7    6
## [3,]    1    2    3    4    6    5    7
## [4,]    1    2    3    4    6    7    5
## [5,]    1    2    3    4    7    5    6
## [6,]    1    2    3    4    7    6    5


# bin, sort and combine according to our binning vector c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3)
rp <- t(apply(p, 1, FUN = function(x) as.numeric(sapply(split(x, c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)), FUN = function(x) paste0(x[order(x)], collapse = "")))))

head(rp)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]   12   34  567
## [2,]   12   34  567
## [3,]   12   34  567
## [4,]   12   34  567
## [5,]   12   34  567
## [6,]   12   34  567


# sort individual combinations before removing duplicates
srp <- t(apply(rp, 1, function(x) x[order(x)]))

head(srp)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]   12   34  567
## [2,]   12   34  567
## [3,]   12   34  567
## [4,]   12   34  567
## [5,]   12   34  567
## [6,]   12   34  567


# remove duplicates
srp[!duplicated(srp), ]
##        [,1] [,2] [,3]
##   [1,]   12   34  567
##   [2,]   12   35  467
##   [3,]   12   36  457
##   [4,]   12   37  456
##   [5,]   12   45  367
##   [6,]   12   46  357
##   [7,]   12   47  356
##   [8,]   12   56  347
##   [9,]   12   57  346
##  [10,]   12   67  345
##  [11,]   13   24  567
##  [12,]   13   25  467
##  [13,]   13   26  457
##  [14,]   13   27  456
##  [15,]   13   45  267
##  [16,]   13   46  257
##  [17,]   13   47  256
##  [18,]   13   56  247
##  [19,]   13   57  246
##  [20,]   13   67  245
##  [21,]   14   23  567
##  [22,]   14   25  367
##  [23,]   14   26  357
##  [24,]   14   27  356
##  [25,]   14   35  267
##  [26,]   14   36  257
##  [27,]   14   37  256
##  [28,]   14   56  237
##  [29,]   14   57  236
##  [30,]   14   67  235
##  [31,]   15   23  467
##  [32,]   15   24  367
##  [33,]   15   26  347
##  [34,]   15   27  346
##  [35,]   15   34  267
##  [36,]   15   36  247
##  [37,]   15   37  246
##  [38,]   15   46  237
##  [39,]   15   47  236
##  [40,]   15   67  234
##  [41,]   16   23  457
##  [42,]   16   24  357
##  [43,]   16   25  347
##  [44,]   16   27  345
##  [45,]   16   34  257
##  [46,]   16   35  247
##  [47,]   16   37  245
##  [48,]   16   45  237
##  [49,]   16   47  235
##  [50,]   16   57  234
##  [51,]   17   23  456
##  [52,]   17   24  356
##  [53,]   17   25  346
##  [54,]   17   26  345
##  [55,]   17   34  256
##  [56,]   17   35  246
##  [57,]   17   36  245
##  [58,]   17   45  236
##  [59,]   17   46  235
##  [60,]   17   56  234
##  [61,]   23   45  167
##  [62,]   23   46  157
##  [63,]   23   47  156
##  [64,]   23   56  147
##  [65,]   23   57  146
##  [66,]   23   67  145
##  [67,]   24   35  167
##  [68,]   24   36  157
##  [69,]   24   37  156
##  [70,]   24   56  137
##  [71,]   24   57  136
##  [72,]   24   67  135
##  [73,]   25   34  167
##  [74,]   25   36  147
##  [75,]   25   37  146
##  [76,]   25   46  137
##  [77,]   25   47  136
##  [78,]   25   67  134
##  [79,]   26   34  157
##  [80,]   26   35  147
##  [81,]   26   37  145
##  [82,]   26   45  137
##  [83,]   26   47  135
##  [84,]   26   57  134
##  [85,]   27   34  156
##  [86,]   27   35  146
##  [87,]   27   36  145
##  [88,]   27   45  136
##  [89,]   27   46  135
##  [90,]   27   56  134
##  [91,]   34   56  127
##  [92,]   34   57  126
##  [93,]   34   67  125
##  [94,]   35   46  127
##  [95,]   35   47  126
##  [96,]   35   67  124
##  [97,]   36   45  127
##  [98,]   36   47  125
##  [99,]   36   57  124
## [100,]   37   45  126
## [101,]   37   46  125
## [102,]   37   56  124
## [103,]   45   67  123
## [104,]   46   57  123
## [105,]   47   56  123
```